# Imagebutton Validation not working

Tags: android, validation, imagebutton

I am trying to put validations in my `ImageButton`'s `onClick()`.  It is like the tile in Boggle game. If I clicked image 1 then the nearest `ImageButtons` must be the only `ImageButton` that is clickable and the remaining buttons will be set as unclickable. How can I achieve it? Here's my code declared at `onCreate()`.

```
public void tileClick() {
        if (image1.isPressed()) {
            image1.setClickable(false);
            image1.setImageResource(R.drawable.changes);

          //clickable when image1 is pressed/clicked
            image2.setClickable(true);
            image5.setClickable(true);
            image6.setClickable(true);

          //unclickable
            image3.setClickable(false);
            image4.setClickable(false);
            image7.setClickable(false);
            image8.setClickable(false);
            image9.setClickable(false);
            image10.setClickable(false);
            image11.setClickable(false);
            image12.setClickable(false);
            image13.setClickable(false);
            image14.setClickable(false);
            image15.setClickable(false);
            image16.setClickable(false);

        }
    }
```

**CustomClickListener** 
//get ImageButton letter

```
    View.OnClickListener myCommoClickListner = new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Log.i(TAG, "arg0.getId()=" + arg0.getId());

                if (arg0.getId()==R.drawable.a){
                    Log.i(TAG,"arg0.getId()="+arg0.getId());
                    generatedString=generatedString+("a");
                    text.setText(generatedString);

   //change ImageButton's background when clicked
                    ((ImageButton) arg0).setImageResource(R.drawable.changea);

   //Set ImageButton clickable = false when already clicked
                    arg0.setClickable(false);

            }
        }
    };

    //all 16 ImageButtons declared like this :

    image1.setOnClickListener(myCommoClickListner);
```

Comment: Can you post the code how you implemented `image1` onClick() ?

Comment: Also, if you could explain what is/isn't happening that would be great

Comment: @codeMagic - Its look like, `image1.isPressed()` is not true as image1's onClick event just passed before it.

Comment: Because it probably isn't in the pressed state anymore. Pass the clicked view and iterate over the buttons and set all but the one that was clicked or however you are doing it

Comment: I put tileClick() on my onCreate().

Comment: Then it will only be called once when the activity is first created. You should call it from your `onClick()` and pass the button pressed

Comment: Are you saying that all 16 ImageButton onClick() will have the same validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your method to accept an `ImageButton`

```
public void tileClick(ImageButton clickedBtn) {
    // validation logic
}
```

pass the clicked `ImageButton` to the function from `onClick()`

```
View.OnClickListener myCommoClickListner = new View.OnClickListener(){
 @Override
 public void onClick(View arg0) {
     ...
     tileClick((ImageButton) arg0) // should change arg0 to something meaningful (v, view, etc...)           
     ...
        }
    }
};
```

Then set the buttons clickable true/false according to the button passed.

You could put the `ImageButtons` in an `Array` and iterate over them and set the clickable according to which button was pressed.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't get it. In tileClick() i'll put my validation? and in myCommoClickListner ?

Comment: Yes, and `myCommoClickListner` is calling that function

Comment: You would need to change it here also `public void onClick(View arg0)`